Why does an external USB DVD rewriter play DVDs, but can't access data or music CDs?
I have two DVD rewritable drives, one external USB and one internal:

LG Electronics External Super Multi DVD Rewriter (model #GSA-E60L) (Drive F:)
Internal DVD rewritable drive (Drive E:)

In Windows 8.1 File Manager, either drive can play a movie DVD by right clicking on the drive.  Both can see the content and access files (except copyrighted VOB files) from both drives.
If I put any music or data CD into the F: drive and close the drive door and left click on the drive in Windows File Manager, it just opens its drive door and a dialog pops up saying:

"Insert disk. Insert a disc.  Please insert a disc into drive F:".

The E: drive can access data and play music CDs. But if I go to Device Manager and attempt to Update Driver Software for the F: drive, then:

"Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date."

Is it even possible to get the external F: drive to access data and play music CDs? It says it's CD compatible. What am I doing wrong?

LASERs fail. There are different lasers for CDs and DVDs. Your CD one failed.

Any way to be sure it's not some other issue?  Any utility that could determine that definitively?  It's been sitting in storage for years.  Hasn't been used, since it was last working.

The DVD and CD reading laser in DVD drives are often the very same laser, so I would not presume that your CD laser had failed, but it's certainly possible. This article explains that in many DVDR/W drives there are three lasers - one low intensity read laser (which is for both CD/DVD), one high-intensity to write, and one medium intensity to erase rewriteable discs.
https://volga.eng.yale.edu/teaching-resources/cds-and-dvds/methods-and-materials
Laser components often fail though, and DVD and CD specifications are different so it's possible your drive has failed in a way that means its now out of spec to be able to read CD correctly but can still read DVD OK. I don't think there's a way to test individual components in your drive short of disassembling it and breaking out the electronics lab (multimeters, oscilliscopes, microscopes etc), unless you have access to LG Electronics manufacturing lab diagnostic software tools, which are not public.
You say it was in storage, was it packed airtight or is it possible it got dusty in storage? If you have some time you could try cleaning the lasers to see if that solves the issue - example: https://youtu.be/pOnS0c6Q6LM

Good advice.  I AM a filthy smoker, and it's questionable how well the rewriter was insulated from my home environments.  Also a good video, as I also love to take things apart and (sometimes) fix them.  Will let you know, if I have any success.  Was only wondering if it MIGHT be a software/driver issue of some kind.  I will take that answer as NO.  Thx.

By the way, here's the Nero Info Tool that MIGHT help some with their drives.
https://www.cdrlabs.com/start-download/misc/33-nero-infotool-5.3.3.0.html
Other suggestions I've seen, remove the driver, restart Windows, then reinstall the driver.  There may be a number of different drivers out there for all I know.  Comments welcome.  Cheers.
